# Change only Font Family via FontDialogBox

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I'm developing a Windows Form App in VB and I want to create a menu where the user can modify `FontStyle` and `ForeColor` of some `Labels`. This `Labels` have specific `Size` according to the GUI.

The idea is to permit the user to change the appearance of the GUI (personalize the font) to be for example more readble. Because of this I need to preserve the ratio between small labels and big labels also in a not absolute precise way (pic)

[image]

I'm already using a `FontDialog` that returns me `Color` and `Font` but applying it (obv) change also the size of the font.

This is a portion of my code now:

```
For Each formLabel As Label In formLabels
                formLabel.ForeColor = FontDialog1.Color
                formLabel.Font = FontDialog1.Font
Next formLabel
```

It's possible to change only the `FontFamily` of a Label (by code)?

Comment: If you change the Font family, also the Font's pitch, kerning, cell ascent and descent measures etc. change, each Font has its own features. Setting the same EM Size doesn't guarantee the same length of the text, quite the opposite. You can always draw graphic text and scale it to the container, if the problem is to prevent your controls from changing size or to avoid clipping the text.

Comment: the idea is to permit the user to change the appearance of the GUI (personalize the font) to be for example more readble. because of this i need to preserve the ratio between small labels and big labels (title, subtitle ecc.) [I edit the question so is more clear for other people]

Comment: Well you can try to keep the same size, no matter what the User choice. e.g., `formLabel.Font = new Font(FontDialog1.Font.FontFamily, formLabel.Font.Size, FontDialog1.Font.Style)`, but, as mentioned, each Font has its own measures. Even if you keep the same em size, the pitch/cell ascent/descent will change. So, you either draw the text inside constrained bound, scaling it, or you make your Layout more *flaxible*. For example, adding those Controls to a TableLaoutPanel (assuming WinForms), so the text on the left will auto-scale the Label which will auto-scale the cell of the TLP.

Comment: Of course, you should try to make your Layout more *flexible*, not *flaxible* :)